# What's a good editor for (La)TeX programming?

Tags: editors, package-writing, documentclass-writing, syntax, big-list

I've found several questions about editors for writing LaTeX *documents* ( [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)  seems to be the definitive one). But I'd like to know which editors are out there that help you develop LaTeX *packages* or *classes*; editors that make it easier to *program* in LaTeX; a completely different activity.

When I'm programming I don't really care about symbol lookup, instant previews, SyncTeX or anything like that. I'd be more interested in features such as those in the following non-exhaustive list:

- an integrated build system and syntax highlighter that understand `.dtx` (and friends)
- smart auto-complete that draws from included packages
- hyper-linking between command definitions and usages
- tool-tips that show command documentation
- native support for `etoolbox`, `etextools`, `latex3` and the like (in some shape or form)
- step-by-step expansion preview of selected code (a form of debugging)
- ability to recognize / select tokens (in addition to characters)
- an `\expandafter`-helper (you just point, the editor inserts the necessary `\expandafter`s)
- automatic searching on CTAN

Well, I could go on, but you get the point.

I call upon all package authors: Which editor do you like? And why? (One editor per answer, please.)

Comment: Ah, but an `\expandafter`-helper would take all fun out of it! :)

Comment: :-) Actually, I'm quite fond of `\expandnext` (and friends) from `etextools`. Wow, did my life get easier when I discovered those. Also, LaTeX3 seems to have nice facilities for expansion control. I listed this feature mainly to give a taste of the kind of thing I'm looking for in an editor.

Comment: Does it have to have a precompiler to see what the argument is ? Where do you want to point exactly to have the array of exapndafters?

Comment: @percusse Just to be clear, that's not the feature that interests me most (that's why it's near the bottom of the list). But no, there would be no need to interpret or pre-compile the code. The editor would merely need to understand what a *token* is. The programmer would first point to the place from where expansion should happen, then select the tokens that should be expanded; perhaps specify how often. <>---<> @ cmhughes I already did the same. :-)

Comment: @mhelvens If you don't mind [the bugs in `etextools`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49606/4427) and the fact that [it breaks other packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65882/4427), then you can "safely" use `\expandnext`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, yes. You're right. :-) But until I learn LaTeX3 I'm sticking with it. (I have only noticed bugs with list-processing, and I know the workarounds.) <>---<> By the way, does LaTeX3 have an `\expandnext` equivalent? Or do I need to define a new function every time I want expansion control?

Comment: @mhelvens Sounds like `\exp_args:No` to me, but our general approach is that expansion is best handled as variants of the 'base' functions.

Comment: I believe this question is very non-constructive and should be closed. To see what editors are popular amongst the TeXy people, see [this community poll](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1567/11002).

Comment: @tohecz I disagree with the closing, voting to reopen. The OP is listing very specific examples of what would be helpful in such an editor. The answers can be objective, contentwise, even though the voting will likely be subjective -- but that's the case with many of our very popular questions, take e.g. [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/553) or [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319)

Comment: See also [Editor for DTX files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31004/)

Answer (score 18):

emacs
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I am resisting adding the obvious rebuttal to this: `vi`. :-)

Comment: -1, would not read again `;)`. (I don't think I need to explain why I don't deem this an adequate answer ...)

Comment: @Manuel : Even if it's not its main purpose, `emacs` can perfectly be used like notepad, with mouse-driven menus instead of strange keyboard shortcuts. It doesn't mean you get locked away from all the "good stuff", you just learn about them at your own pace.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You could turn this into an answer by providing an explanation/justification.

Comment: @Manuel : If you really don't need anything more, there is actually no reason to change your editor. But it is hard to judge if you need something you've never tried (or imagined). You should check questions like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50827/a-simpletons-guide-to-tex-workflow-with-emacs for examples of such features, as well as an (excellent) introduction to emacs.

Comment: I had to override an urge to upvote this because I like emacs. But the truth is this isn't a good answer. [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356/215) is a good answer.

Answer (score 18):

My vote will also go to Emacs.

Using the auctex package with Emacs facilitates easy compilation, syntax highlighting and for those that do use menus there are a lot of TeX/LaTeX resources to be found within the editor with auctex loaded. For the rest of us there are short-codes available through the keyboard - just search for an auctex cheat sheet on the net. However, if you haven't used Emacs or vi/vim before maybe you would like to go for a editor like TeXShop or WinEdt.

Last year a question regarding dtx files and WinEdt was asked and answered.
[Editor for DTX files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31004/editor-for-dtx-files)

Answer (score 7):

I use **TeXstudio** (before called TeXmakerX being a branch from TeXmaker) for some time now and I think it is the best TeX-editor by large.

You can find out more about it at: [its SourceForge site](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/).

It has many nice properties and functions.
The most important ones:

- Multi-platform (Mac, Unix, Windows)
  : you can use one tool everywhere
- concept of *master documents* (really nice when you have many included files in your main TeX file)
  : no need for directives like 'root', no need to switch files
- online preview of the tested file
- macros/scripting
- tool-tips with command documentation
- code folding
- document structure view
- bookmarks
- some directive support, e.g. for spell-checking language

And some others:

- SVN integration (auto-commit at save, get revision at undo, etc.)
- auto-build (compiles bibtex/latex as many times as necessary)
- auto-completion (based on autogenerated `.cwl` files)
- syntax highlighting (tex, latex, lua, qtscript, xml, dtx, ...)
- spell and grammar checking
- many wizards and assistants
- symbol list (latex symbols and more: pstricks, metapost, tikz, asymptote) with favorites
- support for many TeX-tools (bibtex, makeindex, etc.)
- customisation options and profiles
- and more ...

I will just add that I'm not related to the authors of the program, I just use it and find it very useful.

Comment: TeXstudio may be good, but about half of those features are not relevant for programming. :-) It would help if you could clean up your answer a bit to more specifically target the original question.

Answer (score 7):

Can't believe that no one mentioned [VIM](http://vim.sourceforge.net/). It handles e.g. syntax highlighting for dtx files out of the box, but the biggest gain (I can think of) is: You get used to an editor which may serve you for almost all editing tasks (see this [tip](http://pragmatictips.com/22) from the [Pragmatic Programmer](http://pragprog.com/book/tpp/the-pragmatic-programmer)).

Comment: The same could be said for emacs and others. Is latexsuite particularly useful for programming?

Comment: @mhelvens, yes EMacs *is* proposed above and yes latexsuite is very useful for writing latex code.

Comment: Note that 'writing LaTeX code' is not the same as 'LaTeX programming'. Please read the original question more carefully. It is not about preparing LaTeX documents, but about developing packages. I mentioned certain specific features that would be useful for that. Does latexsuite have any of those features?

Comment: Nope, but VIM does handle e.g. dtx files out of the box with correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: That's valid. I request that you edit your answer to more directly address the issue.

Comment: links seem to be dead.

Answer (score 4):

TeXworks has few good properties that might be considered helpful:

- It understands the directive

  ```
  %!TEX root=test.tex
  ```

  which might be useful in a `.sty` or `.cls` file so that you don't have to switch windows to compile the test document.
- It has instant PDF preview of the test file.
- It shows both compilation log and editor window, allowing you to edit the source file during the compilation (however, the compilation runs on the originial file). This allows for very fast and efficient typo corrections.

Comment: Note that TeXworks reads the entire file before allowing editing, which can be a bit 'interesting' with larger source files. (I use TeXworks routinely, so this is not a complaint, just an observation.)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't forget of KDE, you can use Kile. It is good, flexible, fast and whatever else you like. Auto-completion, highlight, patterns included.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I use kile for every LaTeX-related task, i.e., also for package writing, but not because it would have any particluar feature that's helpful for package writing. It simply is the first editor I ever used for LaTeX and I got stuck over the years

Comment: Kile also supports structural view of your document. You can easily find matter section wise, frame wise etc. Also it has nice support for labels and ref. One can easily check if some label went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Most LaTeX-IDEs are quite convenient: all functions are only one klick away. But in most of them the editor sucks. 
If you have ever tried a good editor like vim or emacs you never wanna switch back. 
So I suggest to make your choice of the IDE depending on the editor (or if it's able to use an external editor).

You can also use Emacs or Vim with "plugins". I use Vim with the latex-suite and I've heard the Emacs with AucTeX is even more powerfull.